# Save JavaScript object on JSON grunt task

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm quite new on this tool so i'm trying to use everything i can on tasks. Right now i'm using a plugin to read documents on Google Drive with [grunt-gss-to-json](https://github.com/stpe/grunt-gss-to-json) plugin, the problem is not the reading, is the output. I need to change the way is saved the json because is not compatible with the way i need to read it

Actual output:
all.json

```
[
  {
    "text": "ACCEPT",
    "es": "Aceptar",
    "en": "Agreed"
  }
]
```

Needed output:
es.json

```
{
 "ACCEPT": "Aceptar"
}
```

en.json

```
{
 "ACCEPT": "Agreed"
}
```

I'm thinking about reading the all.json and create based on it the others but I dont know how to write the objects on es.json and en.json files

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I really get the point, but maybe It helps:

```
var obj = [
      {
        "text": "ACCEPT",
        "es": "Aceptar",
        "en": "Agreed"
      }
    ];
    var newObj = {};
    obj.map(function(item){
      newObj["es"]={};
      newObj["en"]={};
      newObj["es"][item.text] = item.es;
      newObj["en"][item.text] = item.en;
    })
    newObj.es; // returns {"ACCEPT": "Aceptar"}
    newObj.en; // returns {"ACCEPT": "Agreed"}
```

Comment: The problem is what the title says, I know how to extract the elements but i dont know how to write them on a grunt task or if exists a better way to do the same task with only 1 plugin (read the document of Google drive and write it correctly on a json file)

Comment: No, you can do as a simple task. I believe what you're looking for is this http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#custom-tasks

Answer (score -1):

`var all = [{"text": "ACCEPT","es": "Aceptar","en": "Agreed"}];
var en = {}
var es = {}
all.forEach(function (single) {es[single.text] = single.es; en[single.text] = single.en;});`

Here we have iterated on all translations and separated them to en and es each